# Pygments piped to less inside python script breaks highlighting

Tags: python, less, pygments

```python
from pygments.lexers import RstLexer
from pygments.formatters import TerminalFormatter
from pygments import highlight

output = highlight(source, RstLexer(), TerminalFormatter())

p = subprocess.Popen('less', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(output)
p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
```

When I just `print output` - everything is ok, but piping breaks highlighting…
Any ideas?

example:

[image: example]

Comment: What do you mean by 'breaks'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's `less`'s fault, not Python's. Run `less` with the `-R` switch:

> **`-R` or `--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS`**
>
> Like `-r`, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form.  Unlike `-r`,
>   the screen appearance is maintained correctly in most cases.  ANSI "color" escape sequences are sequences of the form:
>
> ```
> ESC [ ... m
> ```
>
> where  the  "..."  is  zero  or  more color specification characters For the purpose of keeping track of
>                 screen appearance, ANSI color escape sequences are assumed to not move the cursor.  You  can  make  less
>                 think  that  characters  other  than  "m" can end ANSI color escape sequences by setting the environment
>                 variable LESSANSIENDCHARS to the list of characters which can end a color escape sequence.  And you  can
>                 make  less  think  that  characters other than the standard ones may appear between the ESC and the m by
>                 setting the environment variable LESSANSIMIDCHARS to the list of characters which can appear.